# Python text validation: a-z and comma (",")

Tags: python, regex, validation

I need to check that some text only contains lower-case letters a-z and a comma (",").

What is the best way to do this in Python?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
import string

allowed = set(string.lowercase + ',')
if set(text) - allowed:
   # you know it has forbidden characters
else:
   # it doesn't have forbidden characters
```

Doing it with sets will be faster than doing it with for loops (especially if you want to check more than one text) and is all together cleaner than regexes for this situation.

an alternative that might be faster than two sets, is

```
allowed = string.lowercase + ','
if not all(letter in allowed for letter in text):
    # you know it has forbidden characthers
```

here's some meaningless `mtimeit` results. `one` is the generator expression and `two` is the set based solution.

```
$ python -mtimeit -s'import scratch3' 'scratch3.one("asdfas2423452345sdfadf34")'
100000 loops, best of 3: 3.98 usec per loop
$ python -mtimeit -s'import scratch3' 'scratch3.two("asdfas2423452345sdfadf34")'
100000 loops, best of 3: 4.39 usec per loop
$ python -mtimeit -s'import scratch3' 'scratch3.two("asdfasasdfadsfasdfasdfdaf")'
100000 loops, best of 3: 3.51 usec per loop
$ python -mtimeit -s'import scratch3' 'scratch3.one("asdfasasdfadsfasdfasdfdaf")'
100000 loops, best of 3: 7.7 usec per loop
```

You can see that the setbased one is significantly faster than the generator expression with a small expected alphabet and success conditions. the generator expression is faster with failures because it can bail. This is pretty much whats to be expected so it's interesting to see the numbers back it up.

another possibility that I forgot about is the hybrid approach.

```
not all(letter in allowed for letter in set(text))

$ python -mtimeit -s'import scratch3' 'scratch3.three("asdfasasdfadsfasdfasdfdaf")'
100000 loops, best of 3: 5.06 usec per loop
$ python -mtimeit -s'import scratch3' 'scratch3.three("asdfas2423452345sdfadf34")'
100000 loops, best of 3: 6.71 usec per loop
```

it slows down the best case-ish but speeds up the worst case-ish. All in all, you'd have to test the different possibilities over a sample of your expected input. the broader the sample, the better.

Comment: I personally like the second approach better.

Comment: @Mark but see the timings. It depends on expected inputs.

Comment: nice, i really like the second approach

Comment: @Michał Niklas: This is exactly the kind of job regexes are made for. As you can see from Aaron's comment to Emile's answer, the regex version is several times faster.

Comment: @Tim It's true but in this case I still think that `not all(letter in allowed for letter in letters)` is better then regexes. I mean, that's just plain english pretty much. It's incredibly clear. If it turned out to be too slow for the application, _then_ I would drop it in a heart beat and use a regex. We're talking microseconds here.

Comment: Tim, regex was the first solution I was thinking of. Nice to see other, interesting alternatives. BTW I upvoted regex solutions too :)

Comment: @AaronMcSmooth, correction: allowed = string.lower + ','  --> allowed = string.lowercase + ','

Answer (score 16):

```
import re
def matches(s):
    return re.match("^[a-z,]*$", s) is not None
```

Which gives you:

```
>>> matches("tea and cakes")
False
>>> matches("twiddledee,twiddledum")
True
```

You can optimise a bit with re.compile:

```
import re
matcher = re.compile("^[a-z,]*$")
def matches(s):
    return matcher.match(s) is not None
```

Comment: +1. I don't like it as much as my second solution stylistically but the timing on the precompiled version of this is 3 to 7 times faster than my solutions.

Comment: Can you explain, please, why 're.match(pattern, string)' returns None instead of True/False, while 're.match(pattern, string) is not None' returns the correct values (True if string validation passes, False - if not)?

Comment: h3d0: because re.match() returns either None or a match object; in some cases you care about the match object (it can contain info about what was matched and how, e.g. with named groups); in this case we don't care, we only want to know if it's matched.

Answer (score 3):

```
import re

if not re.search('[^a-z\,]', yourString):
    # True: contains only a-z and comma
    # False: contains also something else
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what do you mean with "contain", but this should go in your direction:

```
reobj = re.compile(r"[a-z,]+")
match = reobj.search(subject)
if match:
    result = match.group()
else
    result = ""
```

Answer (score 1):

Just:

```
def alllower(s):
    if ',' in s:
        s=s.replace(',','a')
    return s.isalpha() and s.islower()
```

with most efficient and simple.

or in one line:

```
lambda s:s.isalpha() or (',' in s and s.replace(',','a').isalpha()) and s.islower()
```

Comment: +1. This is the nicest solution here. I'd forgotten about both of those methods.

Comment: @Kabie Isn't it better if we omit the if statement on the upper code block? `s=s.replace(',','a')` line combs through the string. Is there a reason to comb it one extra time with an if statement?

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import string

text = 'aasdfadf$oih,234'

for letter in text:
    if letter not in string.ascii_lowercase and letter != ',':
        print letter
```

Answer (score 0):

characters a -z are represented by bytes 97 - 122 and ord(char) returns the byte value of the character. Reading the file in binary and making the match should suffice.

```
f = open("myfile", "rb")
retVal = False
lowerAlphabets = range(97, 123)
try:
    byte = f.read(1)
    while byte != "":
        # Do stuff with byte.
        byte = f.read(1)
        if byte:
            if ord(byte) not in lowerAlphabets:
                retVal = True
                break

finally:
    f.close()
    if retVal:
        print "characters not from a - z"
    else:
        print "characters from a - z"
```

Comment: or you could just set `lowerAlphabets = string.lowercase`